# Hough Transform in Python - Results incorrectly offset - index error?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, indexing, hough-transform

I'm writing a basic Hough Transform in Python - I believe I have got it conceptually correct however, my result is appearing to be offset such that it is split top and bottom, rather than continuous. What I want to get should look like this:

[image]

But I get this:

[image]

Which is close, but seems to be split badly through the middle! I'm convinced this is due to my indexing of the rho/theta arrays, however despite my many alterations, I cannot get this to fix! Any explanation of my erroneous step and what I need to change would be very gratefully appreciated!

My source code should be complete and run directly...

Thanks very much

David

**Source**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl

cols, rows = [256,256]  # Set size of image 
grey_levels = 256 #Grey levels in image
testPixels = [[0 for x in range(rows)] for y in range(cols)]  # Convert to black and white
testPixels[100][100] = 255 #Set 3 pixels to white
testPixels[200][200] = 255
testPixels[150][150] = 255

rho_size = int(np.sqrt(rows**2 + cols**2)) #Max possible rho is diagonal dist.
angle_size = 360 #Test all angles

houghspace = [[0 for x in range(rho_size)] for y in range(angle_size)]  # Create hough space array

for x in range(rows):  # For each rows
    for y in range(cols):  # For each cols
        if testPixels[x][y] == 0: #Skip if not edge point
            continue
        for theta in range(angle_size):
            rho = int(x*np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta)) + y*np.sin(np.deg2rad(theta)))
            houghspace[theta][rho] = 255
houghspace = [list(a) for a in zip(*houghspace)] #Transpose to get angle on x axis

fig = mpl.figure()  # Create a figure
fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1).set_title("Original")
mpl.imshow(np.uint8(np.dstack((testPixels,testPixels,testPixels))),cmap='Greys')
fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2).set_title("Hough Transform")
mpl.imshow(np.uint8(np.dstack((houghspace, houghspace, houghspace))),cmap='Greys')
mpl.show()
```

Comment: Will this help? https://youtu.be/hYcugbbf9ug?t=1455

Comment: Is this the answer were you expecting? If not, please let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Comment: I have yet to test but it's the sort of solution I was expecting! I will test, verify and tick as solved asap - thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mixed up the indices when you create `houghspace` as a list of lists. Please prefer using numpy arrays as it will make things much clearer with indices. Along the x-axis, the angle `theta` changes and along the y-axis the `rho` changes. But, you've got it the other way when defining `houghspace` using list comprehension.

Below is the correct code. Note the comments starting with `##`

```
rho_size = int(np.sqrt(rows**2 + cols**2)) #Max possible rho is diagonal dist.
angle_size = 360 #Test all angles

##houghspace = [[0 for y in range(angle_size) for x in range(2*rho_size)]]  #buggy
houghspace = [[0 for x in range(angle_size)] for y in range(rho_size*2)]   #correct
## Also double the rho_size, so that both crust and trough of sinusoidal is visible

for x in range(rows):  # For each rows
    for y in range(cols):  # For each cols
        if testPixels[x][y] == 0: #Skip if not edge point
            continue
        for theta in range(angle_size):
            rho = int(x*np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta)) + y*np.sin(np.deg2rad(theta))) \
                                                  + rho_size  ## also add rho_size
            ##houghspace[theta][rho] = 255   ## buggy
            houghspace[rho][theta] += 255    # <==== indices switched & it's += 
##houghspace = [list(a) for a in zip(*houghspace)] 
##Transposing not needed now (we switched indices)

fig = mpl.figure()  # Create a figure
fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1).set_title("Original")
mpl.imshow(np.uint8(np.dstack((testPixels,testPixels,testPixels))),cmap='Greys')
fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2).set_title("Hough Transform")
mpl.imshow(np.uint8(np.dstack((houghspace, houghspace, houghspace))),cmap='Greys')
mpl.show()
```

---

I get the following plot:

[image]